# What should I say for "Availability" in my CV if I'm applying for another job while currently employed in a part-time job?

Tags: resume

Although it is a part time job (PT), I would prefer not to put my availability as "Immediate" in my CV cause I don't want to just leave my current company too suddenly without at least a week's notice (Don't want to burn my bridges). Theres no contract agreement in my current PT as well.
So what should I put for Availability? And is a week's notice alright for my part time job if I decide to leave?
Thanks!

Comment: The exact answer depends partially on your locality, can you make mention of where you are?

Comment: I live in Hong Kong, China

Answer (score 2):

The 'Availability' section is meant for exactly the type of situation you're in. When someone's unemployed, they are available immediately. When someone's currently employed, their availability is whatever the length of their notice period is.

If you don't have a contract, this notice period depends on what's usual for your location. In the cultures I personally know of, I would advise at minimum to give two weeks of notice to prevent the burning of bridges.

Having said all that, there's nothing forcing you to put your availability on your CV. If your situation is complicated and you'd rather just explain it in words when it comes up, you can just leave it off your CV entirely. In my own personal CV, I don't mention availability anywhere, but it can be inferred from the fact that my most recent working experience is dated *"20xx - current"*. I much prefer to have prospective employers ask me about availability because it also allows me to mention any planned vacation or the like.